how do i verify user using oauth 2 after redirect in callbackURL how to send my session data to frontend
Here is backend....in localhost:3000
import { Router } from "express";
import passport from "passport";
import "../stratergies/DiscordStratergy.js"

const router = Router();

router.get("/discord/login", passport.authenticate("discord"))
router.get("/app/user/auth", passport.authenticate("discord"), (req, res) => {
    console.log(`thiss is${req.user}`)
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
router.get("/auth", (req, res) => {
    const user = req.session.passport
    res.send(user)
    console.log(user)
})


export default router

i am running my front end in localhost:3001
how do i get verification to my fromend?
import Strategy from "passport-discord";
import passport from "passport";
import { UserDiscord } from "../mongooseSchemas/discordUser.js";
var scopes = ['identify', 'email'];

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    console.log("seri");
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
    console.log("dis");
    try {
        const findUser = await UserDiscord.findById(id);
        return findUser ? done(null, findUser) : done(null, null);
    } catch (err) {
        done(err, null);
    }
});


export default passport.use(new Strategy({
    clientID: '1291334889018232862',
    clientSecret: ////
    callbackURL: 'http://localhost:3000/app/user/auth',
    scope: scopes
},
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        let findUser;
        try {
            findUser = await UserDiscord.findOne({ discordID: profile.id })
            if (findUser) done(null, findUser)
            const user = new UserDiscord({
                username: profile.username,
                discordID: profile.id,
                email: profile.email
            });
            await user.save();
            done(null, user)

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
    }));

i did try changing callbackURL to my localhost:3001/home but it doesnot work because there is no code to work with passport in front end.
